# VS2017 Release build not building

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm becoming mad because my visual studio stop builds my solution correctly....
It compiles right only the first time but when i try to recompile it doesn't since a fully system reboot.
Obviously I don't receve any type of error that can let me understand that something went wrong, it compiles successfully but when i deploy apk/ipa or try to debug the code I see that's the oldest one before my updates:

> === Ricompilazione: 2 completate (Completed), 0 non riuscite (failed), 1 ignorate (skipped) ===
>   (the skipped one is ios when I compile for Android and vice-versa)

Below an hilarious problem that let me understand that something went wrong:
[image]

I see that problem only in Release mode and not in Debug mode, and i try evrything:

- Restart visual studio
- clear/rebuild
- delete bin/obj
- clear nugets cache (yes i was desperate).
- clone the Debug mode into a Release2 mode and editing to be similar to Release Mode (and building the project in Release2 mode).
- Close project+vs, delete all msbuild/vs related process into the task manager and restart vs.

My code is made by 3 project:

- proj portable
- proj.droid
- proj.ios

Comment: If you are switching between debug and release builds deployed to the same emulator/device, delete the app from the emulator/device first and then do a clean all/build all/deploy

Comment: Check the date in both the bin release/debug of the file of the executable to see which code is actually getting compiled.

Comment: to jdweng: It compile in the correct folder and update the Last Modified Date.
@SushiHangover: Good idea, it works just the first time... seems to be some type of permission problem to the older app that not allow the newer to overwrite because i got the same bug in both emulator and device.... Any idea?

Comment: @Legion Remove the app from the device/emulator via `adb` and see what the error is (`adb uninstall xxx.yourpackage.name`)

Comment: When cleaning think about deleting all generated obj and bin folders manually

Comment: @SushiHangover: On Friday I got an unistall 'Success' and all works without errors since this morning when the porblem pop-up again.... I'm doing some tests and seems to be an "unistall for all users" problem... sometime Android > 7 start a release/debug session in "another user" and leave the "before user" "busy" since a full shutdown. That not let visual studio to overwrite the app, so it start debug/release on the "busy" one....
Very weird... but is the only solution that i can think.
--------------------------------------
to NickKovalsky: Just done, look the 3rd point of the question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I definitively solve my problem (and is completely different from what i was thinking at the start xD), seems that if your app have some problem during the "automatic package restore" nuget options it doesnt show any error but run the last corrected-compiled version of the software.
In my case i had a problem with my Microsoft.bcl.build package that broke the 'automatic package restore' option. Disabling it and reinstalling the package i can finally compile evrything correctly.